# right associative operator in javacc

Tags: javacc

I need to write a program that checks types for F1 type system and I don't know how to make rules that makes right associative operator.

What I need is that if I parse something like Nat -> Nat -> Nat, that should be parsed as Nat -> (Nat -> Nat), not as (Nat -> Nat) -> Nat (I want to build an AST and do stuff on that)

what I have now is:

```
Node Type2() {Node t1;}
{
    "Nat" { return Node("Nat", null, null);}
    |
    "Bool" { return Node("Bool", null, null);}
    |
    "(" t1=Type() ")" {return t1;}
}
Node Type() {Node t1; Node t2;}
{
    t1 = Type2() (" -> " t2 = Type2() { return Node("->", t1, t2); }
}
```

but it is left associative, how can I make this right?

the grammar is:

```
type              = "Bool" | "Nat" | type, "->", type | "(", type, ")";
lambda_expression = variable
              | "\", variable, ":", type, ".", lambda_expression
              | lambda_expression, " ", lambda_expression
              | "(", lambda_expression, ")";
type_context      = variable, ":", type, { ",", variable, ":", type };
expression        = [ type_context ], "|-", lambda_expression, ":", type;
```

thanks

Comment: I'd suggest skipping whitespace and using `"->"` as the token for the function type operator.

Comment: I can't do that because in lambda calculus the space is the application symbol. I'll add the grammar to the post

Comment: It's your grammar, so you should do what you think best. A more conventional choice would be to skip spaces and use `lambda_expression, lambda_expression` for application. This would allow `f(g x)`, for example. And it would allow more than one space between the function and the argument too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop in place of recursion

```
Node Type() :
{Node t1; Node t2;}
{
    t1 = Type2()
    (   " -> "
        t2 = Type2() 
        { t1 =  Node("->", t1, t2); }
    )*
    {return t1 ; }
}
```

Or --what amounts to the same thing-- use right recursion.

```
Node Type() :
{Node t1;}
{
    t1 = Type2()
    t1 = MoreType( t1 ) ;
    {return t1 ; }
}

Node MoreType(Node t1) :
{Node t2;}
{
    " -> " t2 = Type2() t1 = MoreType( new Node( "->", t1, t2 ) ) {return t1; }
|
    {return t1; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses LL(1) grammar directly:

```
Type2 =
| "Nat"
| "Bool"
| "(" Type ")"

Type =
| Type2 ( "->" Type )?
```

Take parsing `Nat -> Bool -> Nat` as an example:

1. Starting from parsing `Type`, `Nat` is matched by `Type2`.
2. Then the parser sees `->`, so it knows everything inside `( ... )?` should be parsed rather than getting ignored. Now it tries to recursively match `Type` with remaining input, which is `Bool -> Nat`.
3. In this recursive parsing of `Type`, Firstly, `Bool` is matched by `Type2`, then parser sees `->`. So again, it tries to recursively match `Type` with remaining input, which is `Nat`.
4. In the 3rd parsing of `Type`, `Nat` is matched by `Type2`, but parser does not see `->` after it, so it decides to ignore `( ... )?` and terminate.

In the above parsing, `Bool -> Nat` is parsed together in step 2~4, and `Nat -> (Bool -> Nat)` is parsed together in step 1~4. Thus we have obtained right associativity.

Corresponding JavaCC code:

```
Node Type2() :
{ Node t1; }
{
  "Nat" { return new Node("Nat", null, null); }
| "Bool" { return new Node("Bool", null, null); }
| "(" t1=Type() ")" { return t1; }
}

Node Type() :
{ Node t1; Node t2; }
{
  t1=Type2() ( " -> " t2=Type() { return new Node("->", t1, t2); } )? { return t1; }
}
```